# I want to get value from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem - I want to get value from my SQL Server select but it returns:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
```

Code:

```
static SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=True");
static SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM XXX where XXX = 'XXXX'", sqlconnection);

public static string DBSQL()
{
    // connect to database
    sqlconnection.Open();

    // execute  
    SqlDataReader myReader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

    // return valueAC
    return myReader.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Using .ToString() is a code smell - it's often a sign that you're trying to turn something into a string that can't necessarily be represented by a string, or that has other methods to obtain a string value from it. If you find yourself using .ToString - question what you're doing to make sure it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a few steps.  Always consult the [examples provided by the vendor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader).  In particular you're trying to return the *reader itself*, but instead you need to read data from it.  Something like this:

```
SqlDataReader myReader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    if (myReader.HasRows)
    {
        // What should you do if there's more than one row?
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            // Which value are you trying to read?
            return myReader.GetString(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // What do you do when no rows are found?
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
finally
{
    // Make sure to close the reader
    myReader.Close();
}
```

Note a few questions in the code comments that are really up to you to answer:

1. You're selecting potentially zero-to-many records, but trying to return a single value.  What do you want/expect to happen when the result count is anything other than 1?
2. You're doing a `SELECT *`, which is presumably getting more than one value from the database.  Which value are you looking to return?  (And why select more than that one?)

You can decide what to do in those various cases.  But ultimately when using a `DataReader` you need to fetch the rows returned.